# Generate random graphs or randomly rewire graph?

Tags: igraph

I want to compare the dyad census of a directed graph (no loops) with a sample of randomly generated graphs, holding in- and out-degree constant so as to get a better sense if there are more or less of each type of dyad than I'd expect.  I can't understand the difference (if any) between using `sample_degseq` and `keeping_degseq` in conjunction with `rewire`.  Could someone explain it to me, please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sample_degseq` creates a new graph from scratch, given the degree distribution. `rewire` starts from the original graph and iteratively attempts to rewire edges while keeping the degree distribution. As a consequence, the graph obtained from `sample_degseq` is typically independent of the original graph (since the sampling process does not know anything about the exact arrangement of edges in the original graph, only the degree distributions), while `rewire` may preserve some of the structure from the original graph, depending on the number of rewiring steps taken.